# Is there any way to use urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob with ADAL JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, adal

I'm trying to use ADAL to access Microsoft Graph.  Is there any way to use the callback url urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob from the JavaScript client?

I can successfully generate tokens with a c# clinet using that callback and my client id, but I can't figure out how to do it in my React Typescript app.

Answer (score 0):

No.
ADAL.JS is using the Implicit flow, and it wants an https:// redirect URI.
the urn:ietf:wg:oauth2:2.0:oob is for desktop applications